# HTML/CSS/Javascript - table styling issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, html-table

I am printing nout the table in Javascript and accessing it in html. I have features within the code due to which I need to code the tables in Javascript. Each time, the table is printed with random number of columns. I have a styling issue. As you can see in the attached image, Table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhLiE.jpg) to Table [6]  spans the first row of the page while the seventh and eight table appears directly below Table[6]. I need Table[7] to appear from new line, exactly from where Table[9] is appearing. I looked into `nowrap` and `inline-block` but nothing is helping so far. Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h1>Page header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <span id="mText"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var pText = "";
    var mText = document.getElementById("mText");

    for(var i=1;i<40;i++){
        pText += '<div class="col"><table><tr bgcolor="#E5E8E8"><th><h5 style="font-weight: bold;">Table['+i+']: </h5></th></tr>';
        mText.innerHTML = pText;
        for(var j=0;j<(Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 1 + 1)) + 1);j++){
            pText += '<tr><td><h6>Jill</h6></td></tr>';
            mText.innerHTML = pText;
        }
        pText += '</table></div>';
        mText.innerHTML = pText;
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your current CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the width seems to be fixed at having 6 tables per row, while the height is dynamic sized depending on elements, two solutions come to mind.

First solution would be to give each table a min-height css property, since its a table you just declare height.

Second solution create a row for every 6 tables that has display:block, you would check inside your first for loop if i is equal to 1 or when divided by module % 6 create a new row that holds the table. (Doesn't have to be row could be a container of some sort!